# Disable/Hide in built Send button in Outlook form

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-form

I am working on Outlook Addin developed in C# and VS-2008. In this we are having our own custom form .oft
On this form we have our custom “Send” button on click event of it our processing continues.

Now the problem we are facing is we want to disable or hide the built-in send button of Outlook on the Ribbon. Also we want to disable or hide some groups in the Tabs on Ribbon.

We have tried to do this by using custom Ribbon class, implementing `Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility` interface.
In `ThisAddin` file we have written the following method:

```
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility
    CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
{
    return new Ribbon();
}
```

In Ribbon class the xml file is referenced which disable the particular groups from ribbon tab.
But this is applied to all the new mail items not only to my custom form.

Now I just want to at least hide/disable the "Send" button from outlook ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, old question... but for future reference:
To deliver different custom uis for different items you can use Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem when creating the custom ui.
If you need it later, use the ribbons onLoad-event (i.e.: [onLoad="ribbonLoaded"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202.aspx#OfficeCustomizingRibbonUIforDevelopers_Dynamically)).